# Way to save URL + comment into Evernote?

Tags: url, evernote

The Webclipper is too much. I don't want the whole webpage, just the URL and a comment. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Update: 4/26/16

> I use Chrome. I don't want the thumbnail or the sentences. I just want something like "amazon.com/link - this is what I wrote to remind myself why I saved it" Just a one line, no extra stuff. – Joshua Dance

Then my recommendation would be to **select the text**, *right-click*, then *clip bookmark.*

[image: Clip bookmark]

======================

I'm not sure what web browser you are using, but evernote web clipper for chrome has an option where you can save the page as a bookmark.

Evernote will clip a small thumbnail of a page and a 1-3 sentence explaining what it is about.

From there, everything will be normal.

Comment: I use Chrome. I don't want the thumbnail or the sentences. I just want something like "amazon.com/link - this is what I wrote to remind myself why I saved it" 

Just a one line, no extra stuff.